# AngularJS ngTable the pagination not working, showing all data on one page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ngtable

I am using ngTables to load my data in table format and show pagination. My data is loaded from Firebase database and currently the length is 9. So I want to show three lines per page.

Here is my code below, when my page is loaded, all nine lines are loaded on the first page whereas I have set the count to 3, and also when I click on the pages, it doesn't move on.

There is another problem with this, the filtering is not working either.

Here is my ng-table in HTML view doesn't change and :

```
<div ng-controller="mycontroller">
    <strong>Filter:</strong> {{tableParams.filter()|json}}
        <table ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="true" class="table table-striped">
            <tr ng-repeat="obj in mylist">
                <td data-title="'Department'" filter="{ 'name': 'text' }">{{ obj.department }}</td>
                <td data-title="'Lastname'" >{{ obj.lastname }}</td>
                <td data-title="'City'">{{ obj.city }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</div>
```

and `mycontroller.js` :

```
app.controller('mycontroller', ["$scope", "$filter", "ngTableParams", "DatabaseRef", "$firebaseArray",
    function ($scope, $filter, ngTableParams, DatabaseRef, $firebaseArray) {

        //get all data from firebase database
        var mydb = DatabaseRef.ref("projects").orderByKey();
        $scope.mylist = $firebaseArray(mydb);

        var data = $scope.mylist;
        data.$loaded().then(function(data) {
            console.log(data.length); // data is loaded here, and the length is 9
            $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
                page: 1, // show first page
                count: 3, // count per page
                filter: {
                    name: '' // initial filter
                }
            }, {
                total: data.length, // length of data
                getData: function ($defer, params) {
                    // use build-in angular filter
                    var orderedData = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')(data, params.filter()) : data;
                    $scope.users = orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
                    params.total(orderedData.length);
                    // set total for recalc pagination
                    $defer.resolve($scope.users);
                }
            });
        });
    }]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is working solution:

```
app.controller('mycontroller', ["$scope", "$filter", "ngTableParams", "DatabaseRef", "$firebaseArray",
    function ($scope, $filter, ngTableParams, DatabaseRef, $firebaseArray) {

        //get all data from firebase database
        var mydb = DatabaseRef.ref("projects").orderByKey();
        $scope.mylist = $firebaseArray(mydb);

        var data = $scope.mylist;
        data.$loaded().then(function(data) {
            console.log(data.length); // data is loaded here, and the length is 9
            $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
                page: 1, // show first page
                count: 3, // count per page
                filter: {
                    name: '' // initial filter
                },
                sorting: { city: "asc" }
            }, {
            filterSwitch: true,
            total: 0, //data.length, // length of data
            getData: function ($defer, params) {
                // use build-in angular filter
                var filteredData = params.filter() ?
                    $filter('filter')(data, params.filter()) :
                    $scope.mylist;

                var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                    $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, params.orderBy()) : filteredData;

                params.total($scope.mylist.length);
                // set total for recalc pagination
                $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));


                }
            });
        });
    }]);
```

Comment: but filtering is not working! pagination and sorting is working.

Answer (score 2):

- `page` param is extra because default is anyway 1.
- `filter` is extra because by default it is empty as you have.
- `total` is extra because by default it automatically takes the length of dataset
- `getData` is extra. You do not need custom filtering. ngTable does its filtering

I suggest replacing this code

```
console.log(data.length); // data is loaded here, and the length is 9
$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
    page: 1, // show first page
    count: 3, // count per page
    filter: {
        name: '' // initial filter
    }
}, {
    total: data.length, // length of data
    getData: function ($defer, params) {
        // use build-in angular filter
        var orderedData = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')(data, params.filter()) : data;
        $scope.users = orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
        params.total(orderedData.length);
        // set total for recalc pagination
        $defer.resolve($scope.users);
    }
});
```

into this.

```
console.log(data.length); // data is loaded here, and the length is 9
$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
    count: 3, // count per page
}, {
    dataset: data
});
```

and in HTML change this `ng-repeat="obj in mylist"` into this `ng-repeat="obj in $data"`

Comment: this is not working at all! not showing my table, which I am already showing it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example on how to add pagination using `ngTable`.

Obviously, make sure you add reference to angularjs.

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.2/angular.js"></script>
```

Add reference to `ngTable` javascript and css.

```
<link rel="stylesheet"; href="https://unpkg.com/ng-table@2.0.2/bundles/ng-table.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ng-table@2.0.2/bundles/ng-table.min.js"></script>
```

After creating your `ngApp`, create your table inside your view.

Update:

```
<strong>Filter:</strong> {{tableParams.filter()|json}}
<table ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="true" class="table table-striped">
    <tr ng-repeat="obj in myList">
        <td data-title="'Department'" filter="{ department: 'text' }" sortable="'department'">{{ obj.department }}</td>
        <td data-title="'Lastname'" >{{ obj.lastname }}</td>
        <td data-title="'City'">{{ obj.city }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

On your controller, remove `$scope.tableParams` from `data.$loaded()` and use `$scope.myList` directly.

```
app.controller('mycontroller', ["$scope", "$filter", "ngTableParams", "DatabaseRef", "$firebaseArray",
function ($scope, $filter, ngTableParams, DatabaseRef, $firebaseArray) {

    //get all data from firebase database
    var mydb = DatabaseRef.ref("projects").orderByKey();
    $scope.mylist = $firebaseArray(mydb);

    $scope.mylist.$loaded().then(function(data) {
        console.log(data.length); // data is loaded here, and the length is 9
        $scope.arrayLength = data.length;
    });

    $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
            page: 1, // show first page
            count: 3, // count per page
            filter: {
                department: '' // initial filter
            }
        }, {
            total: $scope.arrayLength, // length of data
            getData: function ($defer, params) {
                // use build-in angular filter
                $scope.mylist = $defer.resolve(params.filter() ? $filter('filter')($scope.mylist, params.filter()) : $scope.mylist);
                $scope.users = $scope.mylist.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
                // set total for recalc pagination
                params.total($scope.mylist.length);                    
            }
    });
}]);
```

Comment: i checked everything , and it is alright, but it is still not working! even when I add sortable, again, it is not working, when I click on it, nothing happens.

Comment: @Mpondomise I updated my answer based on your response. Try it out.

Comment: orderedData is not defined. why? i get an error! and also defer resolve line, there is one closing parenthesis missing. please update your answer to get a working version; thanks.

Comment: @Mpondomise sorry about that. Corrected.

Comment: it gives `angular.js:11655TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined` actually this answer here above http://stackoverflow.com/a/40269460/4835480 works for me perfectly fine, but the filtering is not working. how can you fix this? If you fix it, i will accept yours as an answer then.
I had made a mistake, I don't have `users` defined, so I don't need it.